# How do I change a list of lists column into a regular list in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sublist

I have a Pandas DataFrame. One of its columns is a list of lists.

[image]

What is the best way to do the following:

1. Fill the empty lists within the list_of_lists column with the word 'other'? *e.g. [] should become ['other']*
2. Change the list_of_lists column into a regular categorical list? It should end up looking like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons you should not use lists in Pandas series objects. Your first port of call should be to extract the strings and convert you series to categorical data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[], ['steel'], ['steel'], [], ['tarmac'], []]})

df['A'] = df['A'].str[0].fillna('other').astype('category')

print(df)

        A
0   other
1   steel
2   steel
3   other
4  tarmac
5   other
```

---

If you insist on using inefficient and non-vectorisable operations via Python-level loops, then you can achieve what you want this way:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str[0].fillna('other').apply(lambda x: [x])

print(df)

          A
0   [other]
1   [steel]
2   [steel]
3   [other]
4  [tarmac]
5   [other]
```

At this point, categorical data is not an option, because series of lists are not supported by categoricals, since `list` is not hashable.

Comment: Thank you so much jpp. but what is the best way to extract the strings? My data has thousands of instances.

Comment: @V.Desai, I've shown you my first answer.. `str[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.A=[x if x  else ['other']  for x in df.A  ]
df
Out[298]: 
          A
0   [other]
1   [steel]
2   [steel]
3   [other]
4  [tarmac]
5   [other]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick:

```
>>> df
          A
0        []
1   [steel]
2   [steel]
3        []
4  [tarmac]
5        []

>>> df.A.apply(lambda y: "[other]"  if len(y)==0 else y)
0     [other]
1     [steel]
2     [steel]
3     [other]
4    [tarmac]
5     [other]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

OR:

```
  >>> df['A'].apply(lambda x: x if x else ['other'])
0     [other]
1     [steel]
2     [steel]
3     [other]
4    [tarmac]
5     [other]
Name: A, dtype: object
```